How do I chain two router.navigate() calls where history shows both calls
So I have a situation where I am navigating to Component B from Component A with some query params
In the ngOnInit of Component B, we subscribe to a pipeline that, based on the presence of certain query parameters, performs different logic. In one of those pipes, we want to make multiple router.navigate calls, one to overwrite the history, the second to navigate to Component C
ComponentB

myObservable().pipe(
  iif(
    () => queryParamAExists,
    handleQueryParamA(),
    handleQueryParamB()
  )
).subscribe();
  

handleQueryParamA() => {
  of(null).pipe(
    // do some stuff first
    switchMap(() => {
      // the first navigate call is just being made to update our history to prevent the user from accessing this path again. bValue is necessary for handleQueryParamB
      const newParams = {queryParamB: bValue};
      return from(Router.navigate([location.pathname], {state: history.state, replaceUrl: true, queryParams: newParams});
    }),
    switchMap(() => {
      return from(Router.navigate([componentBUrl]));
    })
  );
}

The problem is that for some reason once I land in component C, any history related to Component B is gone, and I am taken back to Component A if I hit back.
I've tried adding a delay between calls, explicitly having the second navigate() call have replaceUrl: false, and adding a separate subscription to the NavigationEnd router.event to make the second call after that.
I also tried chaining the promises as suggested in this answer, but its not working for me.
Chained calls to Angular's router.navigate() behavior regarding query parameters
Is there a way to chain them together Im missing or another way to overwrite history
